# How to read a text file as lines are added

Tags: java, io

I have been asked to write a program that will read a file as it is updated (4 times/millisecond) and print the number of lines to the system. To do this, I have the following code:

```
     package threadFile;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.FileReader;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class ReadFile
{
private String path;

    public ReadFile(String file_name)
    {
        path = file_name;
    }

    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int numberOfLines = readLines();
        String[]textData = new String[numberOfLines];

        int i;
        for(i=0; i< numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }
        textReader.close();
        return textData;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int readLines() throws IOException
    {
        FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

        String aLine;
        int numberOfLines = 0;

        while ((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null)
        {
            numberOfLines++;
        }
        bf.close();

        return numberOfLines;
    }
```

The above code is meant to open a text file and read the number of lines there are. My issue is, getting the program to update as the file is written to (by another section of the program).The below code is a thread, and is meant to call into ReadFile for instructions.
I need the program to constantly read the contents, and accurately update the line count as it is edited.

Comment: Take a look at the [watch service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you want to monitor files for changes? Do you need to re-read the full file? I would not recommend the code your using as if you have large files it will be very inefficient. If you tell me your overal goal i'll try to help more.

Comment: @joey.enfield
Create a program that sets up and initiates 2 threads. Each thread is in it's own class.
The first Thread will open a .txt file and check if there is content, obtain the last line and print it out, then close the file in a loop.
The second needs to open the file, write to it with the current system time/date and print "Number of lines: "<linecount>

The above needs to be constantly looped till terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
The solution to my problem was a little more involved than expected.

**Reading Files**

```
package threadFile;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PrintReader implements Runnable
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final String taskName;

    final String file_name = "C:/Users/wigginsm/Desktop/Log.txt";

    public PrintReader(String name)
    {
        taskName = name;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        boolean loop = true;
        while(loop = true)
        try
        {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file_name);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = br.readLine();
            int count = 0;
            while(line!=null)
            {
                count++;
                line=br.readLine();
            }
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file_name);
            BufferedReader fileR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIn));
            String strLine = null, tmp;
            while((tmp = fileR.readLine())!=null)
            {
                strLine = tmp;
            }
            String lastLine = strLine;
            System.out.println("Last entered line: " + lastLine + "\n" + "Total number of Lines: " + count);
            br.close();
            fileR.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above class is responsible for reading the file, declared with "file_name".

**Writing to Files**

```
    package threadFile;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;
public class WriteToFile implements Runnable
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final String taskName;
    class WriteFile
    {
        private String path;
        private boolean append_to_file = false;

        public WriteFile(String file_path, boolean append_value)
        {
            path = file_path;
            append_to_file = append_value;
        }

        public void writeToFile(String timestamp) throws IOException
        {
            int i = 0;
            while(i<1)
            {
              FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, append_to_file);
              Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
              int ms = current.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
              int minute = current.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
              int second = current.get(Calendar.SECOND);
              int hour = current.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
              int day = current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
              int month = current.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
              int year = current.get(Calendar.YEAR);
              timestamp = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour  + ":" + minute + ":" + second + ":" + ms;

              PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter(write);
              try
              {
                  Thread.sleep(250);
              }
              catch(InterruptedException e)
              {
                  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              }
              print_line.printf("%s" + "%n", timestamp);
              print_line.close();
            }
       }
    }
    //constructor
    public WriteToFile(String name)
    {
        taskName = name;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public synchronized void run()
    {
        boolean loop = true;
        while(loop = true)
        {
            try
            {   
                String file_name = "C:/Users/wigginsm/Desktop/Log.txt";
                Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
                int ms = current.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                int minute = current.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int second = current.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                int hour = current.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int day = current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
                int month = current.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                int year = current.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                String timestamp = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour  + ":" + minute + ":" + second + ":" + ms;
                WriteFile data = new WriteFile(file_name, true);
                data.writeToFile(timestamp);
            }

            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is responsible for writing to the file. The only reason for the while loop to continue indefinitely is due to my program specification. This can easily be altered to fit any iteration.

**Execution**

```
package threadFile;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class execute
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String file_name = "C:/Users/wigginsm/Desktop/Log.txt";

        WriteToFile writes = new WriteToFile(file_name);
        PrintReader reads = new PrintReader(file_name);
        ExecutorService thread = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        thread.execute(reads);
        thread.execute(writes);

        thread.shutdown();
    }
}
```

This is the main class, it is responsible for handling the threading. Both PrintWrite and WriteToFile have the "synchronize" statement, as run() in both classes accesses the file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your requirement you want to use one file for Inter Process Communication (or inter thread-communication to be more exact for your case). If this is the case you probably want to use the file as MemoryMapped file.

A simple description of MemoryMapped file usage is done [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/power-of-java-memorymapped-file.html).

As it was already said, Java 1.7 [Watch Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) is also a solution that could work.